# Can't turn down HtmlUnit logging

Tags: log4j, htmlunit, apache-commons-logging

I'm using org.apache.log4j.Logger and want to turn off debug messages for htmlunit.  Nothing I do seems to work.  I keep getting Http.wire, Http.headers, etc debug messages.   I have the root logger set to debug

I tried placing this line in my code:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
```

I also tried placing this line in my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit=WARN
```

This is the contents of my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit=ERROR

log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=ERROR


# Tell the root lodger what appenders and level to use
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1, A2


##### Console Appender #####

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %-17c{2} (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n


##### File Appender #####

log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.File=/var/log/mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %-17c{2} (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n
log4j.appender.A2.Append=false
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 11/15/16 (Adding test code)

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;

import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.apache.commons.logging.*;
import org.apache.log4j.*;

public class Test01
{
    @Test
    public void homePage() throws Exception
    {
        LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger");
        LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger");


        org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.WARN);
        org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.WARN); 

        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);


        Logger.getRootLogger().debug("Start");

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient()

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://google.com");

        Logger.getRootLogger().debug("End");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much experimenting and observation of the log output I have figured this out.  As it turns out the documentation for HttpClient on the  [Apache HTTPCLient website](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html) is not correct (as a matter of fact there are broken links). It turns out the names of the loggers used by HTTPClient are not as specified in the doc.  The correct logger root name is "http" not "httpclient" which means all the trials I was performing had zero effect.

I am using org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5.2 and org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.4.5 which as of today (11/15/16).

Here is an example log4j.properties file that will allow fine control of the HTMLClient logging

```
# Tell the root logger what appenders and level to use
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1, A2


# Controls detailed wire protocol
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=WARN

# Controls headers (good for debugging)
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.headers=WARN

# Controls http context (what you are sending and geting)
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=WARN

# Controls htmlunit details
log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit=WARN


##### Console Appender #####

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %-17c{2} (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n


##### File Appender #####

log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.File=mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %-17c{2} (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n
log4j.appender.A2.Append=false
```

Answer (score 0):

For log4j, you should set `log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit` to `ERROR`:

```
log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit=ERROR
```

Second option : in your code, add this after declaring your web client:

```
LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit=ERROR in the properties file does nothing.  The code snippets work but it turns off the debug logs of the root logger.  I've tried SimpleLog and also Log4JLogger without luck.  I'm having trouble understanding why settings in my log4j.properties file can't set different levels for different loggers.  I've updated my orginal question with log4j.properties file I'm using.

Comment: BTW.  I have the same problem with Authorize.net logging html wire details.

Comment: After experimenting with this it appears that only the root logger is used.  Setting levels and attributes of org.apache.commons.logging.Log and  com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit don't have an effect.  The only thing that works is if I set a level in the log4j.properties file or I do a Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN).  Both of those solutions effect all logging not just the individual ones I would like to control.  This can't be this hard to do, am I missing something?